# How to set a Filter for the ComboBox List Items Edit Form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

**Short form of the question**:

How can I set a filter for the form which is used by the "List Items Edit Form" property of a ComboBox?

**Long description of the environment**:

In my database, there is a growing number of structurally similar values which describe something. I collated all of these in one table named ComboTexts, and added a second table ComboTextTypes to customize the field names on the user side. Example:

```
ComboTexts table:
ID    s1    s2            s3                                     TypeID
1     1     First Floor   Ground Floor                           2
2     2     Second Floor  Null                                   2
3     AOX   DIN 1485      determination of organic components    3

ComboTextTypes table:
ID  formtitle  ch1             ch2           ch3
2   Floor      Floor Number    Floor Name    Alternate Name
3   Process    Process name    Standard      Description
```

In order to edit entries in ComboTexts, I provide two forms: The form CoreData displays the list of formtitles from ComboTextTypes and an "edit" button. When the user selects a fomtitle and clicks "edit", the form EditComboTexts is called with a filter for TypeID set. EditComboTexts extracts the TypeID from its filter and modifies itself with the information from ComboTextTypes.

So far there exist 14 ComboTextTypes in the database, and that number is growing. I simply didn't want to have 14 or more tables and forms, which basically all do the exact same thing. Instead I just have two tables and forms, although a little more complicated ones.

The above mechanic is all set up and works fine.

**Description of the problem**:

The users want to be able to modify the 14th ComboTextType from inside the combobox. The detour through CoreData is three clicks too many, they know that ComboBoxes can offer an edit button for their value list, and want to use it at that point.

Access offers the "List Items Edit Form" for this purpose. When I enter the EditComboTexts form there, it's working in principle, but (of course) the filter is wrong.

How can I set a filter for that form?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the rowsource using SQL and simply change the rowsource value of the combo box

```
Me.Combo0.RowSource = "SELECT myfield FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.myfilter = 'value' ; "
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. Unfortunately, the rowsource filter is not passed to the edit form - it opens with the unfiltered, complete list.

Comment: Don't use the filter option, instead put your WHERE condition directly into the rowsource SQL. You can leave the filter blank and have a query in the rowsource that only returns the records you want. Can you send a small sample of the code you are using?

Comment: I'm doing all that. I put a minimal example database [here](http://ebruenner.de/download/test.zip). The example contains a form "OtherForm" which shows the problem. It can be seen when clicking the edit button which appears after the combo-list drops down - ComboTexts operates on the whole set of texts, not only the floors.